# what version of jquery UI can work with jquery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have jquery 1.3.2 on my site(and I cant update it).
what version of jquery UI can I download, for they to work together?
Can You post a link to download, I didn't find older versions on jquery site.

Comment: Would you be so kind to elaborate on why you can't update jquery 1.3.2? are you using some kind of CMS  system that has jquery 1.3.2 built in?

Answer (score 10):

You can use jQuery UI `1.7` - `1.8.24`

see full list of dependencies `-->` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI

Download links:

- http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui-1.8.24.zip
- http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/09/jquery-ui-1-8-24/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jQuery UI 1.8` take a look here: http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/

There is a clear documentation about compatibility:

> This site provides
>   API documentation for jQuery UI 1.8. We encourage you to upgrade to
>   the latest stable version of jQuery UI in order to receive the best
>   support and take advantage of recent bug fixes and enhancements. Check
>   out the upgrade guides and changelogs to find out more about
>   upgrading. To get started, use the search at the top of the page, view
>   the full listing of entries, or browse by category from the sidebar.
>
> jQuery UI 1.8  supports jQuery 1.3.2 and newer.

Download links here: http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/09/jquery-ui-1-8-24/

But I hope you will update the jQuery core library will be safer and faster.

Answer (score 0):

So far I see on github repository, the version you're looking for is [jquery-ui 1.7](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/1.7).

It's possible that greater versions work the same as other pointed out.